# Why don't my lights work after I added a GFCI outlet to the circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I replaced an old outlet with a GFCI outlet in my bathroom.  I know that I've installed it correctly because I've tested it with a night light.  But I can't get the light fixture above my vanity to turn on now.  I've also tested the light bulbs elsewhere to make sure that they work.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Testing it that way doesn't prove that you don't have line and load reversed, which I suspect is your problem.

Comment: I found the black line one with a voltage tester though.

Comment: And it's installed on the LINE side of the outlet? Maybe post a photo of the connections to help us spot other issues.

Comment: It works!!!  Thanks so much!  They weren't switched but I think one connection was just a little loose.  Have a great day!  What a relief.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one whole group of outlets stop working, but the wires to one plug on one outlet are still hot?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36527/how-can-one-whole-group-of-outlets-stop-working-but-the-wires-to-one-plug-on-on)

Comment: Rob, please delete your post or provide an answer below so it can be resolved.